# gcc builtin atomic compare and exchange

Tags: c, gcc, atomic

I want to use the gcc builtin function `__atomic_compare_exchange()` but I need it slightly different than it is specified as and it I am unsure it`s possible to achieve.

the function prototype:

`__atomic_compare_exchange(type *ptr, type *expected, type *desired, bool weak, int success_memmodel, int failure_memmodel)`

it atomically compares `ptr` to `expected` and writes `desired` into `ptr` if `ptr` == `expected`

what I want to achieve is very similiar but my `expected` is `!= NULL`, basically I want to check if `ptr != NULL` and if that is true write `desired` into `ptr`.

can this be done?

here is the gcc concerning its usage:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but you just have to call it in a loop. On each loop iteration, read the old value. If it's null, break out of the loop and return failure. If it's not null, use that old value as the "expected" for atomic compare-and-exchange. If it succeeds, exit the loop and return success. Otherwise repeat.

By the way, this general approach is how you construct arbitrary atomic operations on top of compare-and-exchange.

Comment: but then I lose atomicity, its important for me that both the read compare and write together are atomic. If it isn`t there is a race condition where the data can change between the read, compare and write

Comment: No, you don't lose atomicity. That's the whole point. Atomic compare-and-swap gives you any atomic operation you want via this method. If the data changes between the read of the old value (to get "expected") and the atomic cas, the cas fails and you start over.

Comment: important to mention - re general practice - you need some random backoff in the loop. Imagine many threads repeating perpetually perfectly synced loops and never get to action.